# logstash track all changes (addition of rows, modification of column in a row or deletion of rows) in csv file and update it in an index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a configuration csv file, which gets updated {i.e. addition of rows, modification of column in a row or deletion of rows} by an application in order to ensure that configuration data is most recent.

My requirement is to read the configuration csv file using logstash pipeline and update the configuration data into an index.

To achieve this requirement, I created a  configuration.conf Logstash pipeline as mentioned below; however, when I tested the configuration.conf file, it only inserts the new rows to the index and modified the field's value in existing document.

Can someone please assist me with the conf changes required in configuration.conf to delete the document from index, when row in csv file is deleted? So that index in Elasticsearch gets synchronized with main configuration csv file.

configuration.conf

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/etc/logstash/pipelines/configuration.csv"
         start_position => beginning
        #sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        sincedb_path =>"/etc/logstash/pipelines/sincedb.log"
        sincedb_clean_after =>  "10 seconds"
        mode  => "read"

    }
}
filter {
if [message]{
    csv {
          columns => [ "id", "empId","empName","emaiIId"]
         }
}
}

output {
if [empId]{
elasticsearch {
    id => "configuration-output"
    hosts => ["localhost:441"]
    index => "configuration_index"
    user => "logstash"
    password => "****************"
    timeout => 30
    doc_as_upsert => true
    action => "update"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
}
```

configuration csv file :

```
id, empId,empName,emaiIId
1,111,emp01,emp01@gmail.com
2,222,emp02,emp02@gmail.com
3,333,emp03,emp03@gmail.com
```

Thanks and Regards,
Nivedita